# How to change css classes with a button click in javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm confused on what I'm doing wrong here I'm following a tutorial and it works fine for them but not me. I've switched around many things to try to find the problem but it just doesn't seem to work.

HTML

```
<h1 class="settingOne" id="mainText">Simple HTML Page</h1>
    <p class="center">
        This is a very simple HTML page.
    </p>

    <p class="center">It's about as basic as they come. It has: </p>

    <ul class="center">
        <li>An H1 Tag</li>
        <li>Two paragraphs</li>
        <li>An unordered list</li>
    </ul>

    <button id="changeButton">
        <p>
            Hey push this to change the header thing
        </p>
    </button>
```

CSS

```
.settingOne {
    font-family: fantasy;
    color: blue;
    text-align: center;
}

.settingTwo {
    font-family: serif;
    color: red;
    text-align: center;
}
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
function changeClass() {
    document.getElementById("changeButton").onclick = function () {
        if (document.getElementById("mainText").className === "settingOne") {
            document.getElementById("mainText").className = "settingTwo";
        } else {
            document.getElementById("mainText").className === "settingOne";
        }
    };
}

window.onload = function () {
    preparePage();
}
```

;

Comment: You are not calling the function

Comment: Call changeClass() from within your onload handler. (And what is preparePage(), which you call from onload but haven't shown.)

Comment: `document.getElementById("mainText").className === "settingOne";`
you should assign value on this line, in else statement, not check

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not clear if your `changeClass` function is ever called. I provide an example that cleans up your code a bit by storing the first query to the element `changeButton` in the variable `ele` and then registering the click handler when the `window.onload` event occurs. You could of course wrap this all up in another function called `registerHandlers` or put it in your `preparePage` function instead.

```
window.onload = function () {
    var ele = document.getElementById("changeButton");
    ele.onclick = function() {
        if(ele.className === "settingOne") {
            ele.className = "settingTwo";
        } else {
            ele.className = "settingOne";
        }
    };
};
```

Comment: When I used it changed the text of the thing that was triggering the onClick but I added another variable that was connected to the h1 tag i wanted to changed moved some stuff around and boom there it was. Thank you :D and sry about the question not being that descriptive im still getting used to both stack overflow and javascript.

Answer (score 4):

In the Javascript, the line

```
else { document.getElementById("mainText").className === "settingOne"; }
```

should be changed to

```
else { document.getElementById("mainText").className = "settingOne"; }
```

The single = is used to set one thing equal to another, which is the behavior you want here.

Working example: https://jsfiddle.net/w6no44v1/20/

Comment: I did what you said and your right it was wrong.... don't know how i missed that. It didn't fix the problem though someone in the comments above told me to call the changeClass function not sure where to though, I'm new to this so I'm just testing the waters. Oh and I got rid of the preparePage()

Comment: Just added a JSFiddle link with sample code for you! Let me know if this is helpful. :)

Comment: Also be sure to note where your Javascript is placed--is it in the <head> or at the end <body> of your HTML file? You haven't specified that in your question, but the placement does matter for this example. (In my JSFiddle sample, it's in the body.) Happy coding!